# Android: Get download URL from Firestorage after uploading Image bitmap

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore

My firestore reference:

```
  storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("/folder/photo.jpg");
```

I use a camera intent to get an image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
```

On activity result I get the image and upload it:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putStream(bs);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {

           new L().info(storageRef.getDownloadUrl()+"");
            new AlertUtil().showCustomAlert(this,"done");
        });
        }
    }
```

However the storageRef.getDownloadUrl() returns this:

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@64b8bf6
```

The code is from the documentation:
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files][1]

What am I missing here? How do I get the download URL

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
StorageReference photoRef = mSRreference.child(selectedImageUri.toString());
photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot){
        // your download uri - taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()
    }

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
});
```

Comment: data.getData() returns null it's a bug i worked on it for an hour, getting the imageuri using File provider needs the image to be  temporarily saved on the external storage to get the uri. Add permissions and all sorts of unnecessary code. I found a very easy way I'll post it in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask...` code from the documentation and it did not work.

So I tried uploading the file then getting the image url which seemed like the simplest way to go and it worked:

```
  UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putStream(bs);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(task ->
                        new L().info("url" + task.getResult()));
            });
```

I would like to point out that the documentation is not very good. I am using java 1.8 hence the shorter lamba syntax. Add

```
compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

to your app build.gradle to do so.